# disable boost in hibernate search [issue in mapping index in elasticsearch, via hibernate search]

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate with Hibernate search to index the classes + data in elastic search(from java to elasticsearch). I've set it up and provided all the properties. 
For ex:

```
@Entity
@indexed(name="a")
public class a{

@Id
@Generated value
private integer i;

@Field(index=index.yes, analyze=analyze.no, store=store.yes, norms = norms.no)
private String b;
//Getter and Setter
}
```

In my main method i'm passing values into this class and persisting. When I do that I'm getting error message which says

The [string] type is removed in 5.0. You should now use either a [text] or [keyword] and automatic upgrade was disabled because of boost parameters.

To give you more details

it is sending Json input in this pattern

```
PUT a/a_mapping
{
 "properties":{
   "i":{
     "type": "String"
     "boost":1.0,
     "index": not_analyzed
     "store":yes
    },
    "b":{
     "type": "String"
     "boost":1.0,
     "index": not_analyzed
     "store":yes
```

What I've understood after playing around is String data type are deprecated in ES 5.0, so the **'String'** data going in, has to be transformed into either **'Keyword'** or **'Text'**, Hibernate Search orm does this, provided there is no boost parameter (i tried to manually input this with and without boost parameter, it worked in latter).

So I've come to conclusion that I have to to one these two options to send data through hibernate to ES.

1) Either built a fieldbridge which will convert datatype from object to Keyword

2) Disable index time boosting parameter so that boost is not input while indexing.

So far I've not been able to find solution to either of these, any tips or help will be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, Hibernate Search 5.6 and 5.7 will only work correctly with Elasticsearch 2.x. These versions will only use the "string" datatype, never "text" or "keyword".
Hibernate Search 5.8 adds support for Elasticsearch 5. It is almost ready, but has only been available as Beta versions for now (Hibernate Search 5.8.0.Beta4 being the latest). Note that if you're migrating from Elasticsearch 2, you will have to drop your old indexes and reindex everything.

Second, index-time boosting [has been removed in Elasticsearch 5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/index-boost.html), so you should use query time boosting instead.

Comment: I saw your post on 5.8 beta on hibernate website, it has resolved all the issues i had mentioned in questions. Thanks for all the information.

Comment: @BadumTsch No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issues :)